# How to display:none webpart Update

Tags: web-part

I get all webparts that I have in `default.aspx` using this code

```
var pageName = "/sites/default.aspx";
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var pageFile = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageName);
var webPartManager =   pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webPartDefs = webPartManager.get_webParts();
ctx.load(webPartDefs,'Include(WebPart)');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
 function () {
    for(var i = 0;i < webPartDefs.get_count();i++) {
       var webPartDef = webPartDefs.getItemAtIndex(i);
       var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();

       var title = webPart.get_title();
   });
```

I get here 4 webparts, Webpart1,Webpart2,Webpart3,Webpart4

Of this 4 webparts I want to set `display:none` on Webpart1,Webpart2,Webpart3,
So I only want to display Webpart4.

How could I create an array of the webparts that I want to display, and then check if my title of webparts contains that and then if it contains `display:none` on them and do nothing with

```
var webPartsArray = ["Webpart1", "Webpart2", "Webpart3"];
```

## UPDATE

====================================
My webpart wont hide?

```
function init() {

var pageName = "/sites/default.aspx";
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var pageFile = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageName);
var webPartManager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webPartDefs = webPartManager.get_webParts();
ctx.load(webPartDefs, 'Include(WebPart)');


ctx.executeQueryAsync(
function () {
    var pageWPArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < webPartDefs.get_count() ; i++) {
        var webPartDef = webPartDefs.getItemAtIndex(i);
        var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();

        pageWPArray.push(webPart.get_title());
    }
    var webPartsArray = ["Webpart1", "Webpart2", "Webpart3"];

    for (var j = 0; j < pageWPArray.length; j++) {

        for (var i = 0; i < webPartsArray.length; i++) {

            if (pageWPArray[j].indexOf(webPartsArray[i]) > -1)
                alert("pageWPArray:" + "" + pageWPArray[j] +" "+ "=:" + " " + (webPartsArray[i]));
            {

                jQuery("#"+webPartsArray[i]).hide();
            }


        }

    }

},
function (sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
}


);
```

}

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init, 'SP.js');
```

## ====================================

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It assumes the WebPart title is the ID in the DOM

```
var pageWPArray;

function () {
for(var i = 0;i < webPartDefs.get_count();i++) {
   var webPartDef = webPartDefs.getItemAtIndex(i);
   var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();

   pageWPArray.push(webPart.get_title());
});

//Loop through your array of Web Parts you'd like hidden
for (var i = 0; i < webPartsArray.length; i++) {
    //Does your array contain this value?
    if(pageWPArray.indexOf(webPartsArray[i]) > -1)
        $("#" + webPartsArray[i]).hide());
}
```

Comment: It does not hide my webparts?

Comment: I am not getting the id, i am geting the webpart title and also have a an array of the webparts titles that i want to hide? @Reek

Comment: I will update the code that i have now.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you are trying to run the above code from the same page (default.aspx)

If so, you can actually run the normal jQuery code to get the webpart divs and hide them according to your requirement.

The following code will give you all the webpart divs with "webpartid" custom attribute

$('div[webpartid]')

just loop through the list above and hide the webpart divs accordingly

```
$('div[webpartid]').each(function(e){
 if($(this).attr('id') != 'WebPartWPQ4')
 {
   $(this).hide();
 }
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Hi, but the id of the webpart sare not the same every time, i never now if it would be WebPartWPQ4 or WebPartWPQ5 or non of them? Thats why i want to get them by title and compare to my array and then hide. if i was so simple if the webparts always hade the same id, could set on them display:none;

Comment: Hello TheRock,

If you can give me the full requirement, I can help you better. Even in your question I see some IDs or Titles hard coded. 

I reckon you can still read the values from some SharePoint list if you are storing the values for which web part you wanna show/hide on some page. 

If you are going by the Titles of the web part also you must have been storing those values somewhere and read them from there using CSOM.

Comment: I have posted my full code,? The titles of the webparts are hard coded yes, they should be that.